# How to derive this Matsubara sum, as presented in Wikipedia?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, regularization

[On the Wikipedia page for Matsubara frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency), the following formula is presented,
$$
\sum_{i\omega_n} \frac{(i\omega_n)^2}{(i\omega_n)^2 - \xi^2} = -\frac{\xi}{2}\Big(1 - 2 N_{\text{FD}}(\xi)\Big),
$$
where $\omega_n = (2n+1)\pi/\beta$ are fermionic Matsubara frequencies and $N_{\text{FD}}(x):= (e^{\beta x}+1)^{-1}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution function.

I am familiar with the residue theorem and I can derive `easier' results involving Matsubara summations. However, in this case I don't see how to derive the result. I guess it is necessary to include the usual converging factor $e^{i\omega_n\eta}$ with $\eta\rightarrow0$ at the end of the computation, otherwise the sum would not even converge. Any help or reference would be appreciated.

The reason I am asking this, is because I actually want to evaluate a Matsubara sum of the form
$$
\sum_{i\omega_n} \frac{(i\omega_n)^2}{(i\omega_n - \xi_1)(i\omega_n - \xi_ 2)}.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was overlooking something obvious. My reasoning was: there are two poles located at $i\omega_n = \pm \xi$, how come there is only a Fermi-Dirac distribution evaluated at one pole? Using the identity $N_{\text{FD}}(-x) = 1 - N_{\text{FD}}(x)$ solves this problem. Indicating the usual steps by dots (going to the complex plane; closing the contour appropriately etc.), one obtains

\begin{align}
\sum_{i\omega_n} \frac{(i\omega_n)^2}{(i\omega_n)^2 - \xi^2} &= \sum_{i\omega_n} \frac{(i\omega_n)^2}{(i\omega_n - \xi)(i\omega_n + \xi)} \\
&=\dots \\
&=\frac{\xi^2}{2\xi}N_{\text{FD}}(\xi)+\frac{\xi^2}{-2\xi}N_{\text{FD}}(-\xi) \\
&=-\frac{\xi}{2}\Big(1 - 2 N_{\text{FD}}(\xi)\Big)
\end{align}